# How to validate Complete in AKKA-HTTP

Tags: json, scala, akka-http

I want to validate the result of the complete function of my API, the Response generates a null when it can not transform the String to a Json type, I do not want it to generate null but say: "not found", this is my route:

```
 val route = pathPrefix("auth") {
    path("signIn") {
      pathEndOrSingleSlash {
        post {
          entity(as[LoginPassword]) { loginPassword =>
            val a = signIn(loginPassword.login, loginPassword.password).map(_.asJson)
             if(signIn(loginPassword.login, loginPassword.password).map(_.asJson) == null){
               complete(states.map(_.asJson))
             }else {
               def getObject : Option[Any] = Option(signIn(loginPassword.login, loginPassword.password).map(_.asJson))
               val ahh = signIn(loginPassword.login, loginPassword.password).map(_.asJson)
               if(getObject.isEmpty || getObject == null){ ///////NOT FOUND
                 complete("Not Found")
               }else {
                 complete(signIn(loginPassword.login, loginPassword.password).map(_.asJson)
               }
               //complete(signIn(loginPassword.login, loginPassword.password).map(_.asJson))
             }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

this does not work, since it always enters the else within the condition, responding a Json when it gets the value in BD and null when not.

**Function Sign**

```
 def signIn(login: String, password: String): Future[Option[TokenEntity]]   = {

db.run(users.filter(u => u.username === login).result).flatMap { users =>
  users.find(user => Bcrypt.validate(password, user.password)) match {
    case Some(user) => db.run(tokens.filter(_.userId === user.id).result.headOption).flatMap {
      case Some(token) => Future.successful(Some(token))
      case None        => createToken(user).map(token => Some(token))
    }
    case None  => Future.successful(None)
  }
}
}
```

The Json library I use is: [Json](https://circe.github.io/circe/)

Some help? Thanks.

Comment: This is a very difficult question to answer without knowing the signature of `signIn` and what JSON library you're using. The `states` value also comes out of nowhere. Also, why are you calling `signIn` multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stopped to think things through and how to solve what I needed and first to validate that it was a valid response was to analyze the response of signIn:

- Assign the response to a val

  ```
  val token = signIn(loginPassword.login, loginPassword.password)
  ```

token is of type: Future[Option[TokenEntity]] and I need to work with: Option[TokenEntity] and validate if it is a correct answer:

```
       val response = token.map(_ match {
        case Some(token) => prepareHttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, token.asJson.toString)
        case None => prepareHttpResponse(StatusCodes.Unauthorized, "{reason: \"not found\"")
      })
```

if it is valid I respond in format Json the Token but I respond with: not found
finally was:

```
 val route = pathPrefix("auth") {
    path("signIn") {
      post {
        entity(as[LoginPassword]) { loginPassword =>
          val token = signIn(loginPassword.login, loginPassword.password)
          val response = token.map(_ match {
            case Some(token) => prepareHttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, token.asJson.toString)
            case None => prepareHttpResponse(StatusCodes.Unauthorized, "{reason: \"not found\"")
          })
          complete(response)
        }
      }
    }
```